# Is google ranking higher social media and forum answers in results?

Tags: seo, google, search-results

I know SERP pages can differ based on search history and other factors, but on my computer on Mar. 17, 2024, this search:

"social media has so many views it destroys brain"

highlights a goddamn Medium article as the #1 result. That's just ridiculous.

Whereas on Bing, the same search term reveals an article from PsychologyToday as the first result.

And in general, I keep seeing posts from reddit and quora popping up on informational searches where anyone can answer and any bias can be stated.

Comment: Reddit and quora are seeing the benefits of branded search, people were adding their names to the search query to see if their results were better for informational searches. Google gives people what they want.

If Reddit or Quora are showing in the results ... The search intent would likely be informational.

People adding -site:reddit.com to the query will likely reverse the situation.